# Auto-registration of dependencies with MS DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, auto-registration

```
    services.AddSingleton<NavigationBarViewModel>();
    services.AddSingleton<FileHandlingViewModel>();
    services.AddSingleton<SchedulingProblemViewModel>();
    ....

    services.AddSingleton<Func<FileHandlingViewModel>>((s) => () => s.GetRequiredService<FileHandlingViewModel>());
    services.AddSingleton<Func<SchedulingProblemViewModel>>((s) => () => s.GetRequiredService<SchedulingProblemViewModel>());
    services.AddSingleton<Func<TimeIntervalsViewModel>>((s) => () => s.GetRequiredService<TimeIntervalsViewModel>());
    ...
```

I register a bunch of `Func` as indicated above into MS DI container. I can list the relevant types with reflection. I can auto-register the types, but I also want to auto-register the `Func`s with `foreach`. Any idea for the later?

Comment: A) Why are you registering a _view model_ in DI? B) How do you use the `Func` version of the DI entry in your code?

Comment: It is part of the navigation infrastructure of a WPF application (switching between pages). I learnt it from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N26C_Cq-gAY&t=5s&ab_channel=SingletonSean). But my question is more general, how to auto-register factory methods.

Comment: It might be that MS DI does not have such advanced features. It is worth taking a look at Autofac: https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html The good news is that Autofac can be used on top of MS DI. So you can keep your existing registrations as they are and add new ones using Autofac.

Answer (score 0):

It seems auto-registration of factory method can not be done in MS DI. The problem is that we can create the factory method with `MakeGenericMethod` but this method still needs an explicit cast what we can not use in an auto-registration loop.

Workaround: Use factory class instead of factory method.

```
public class PageViewModelFactory<TPageViewModel> where TPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider services;

    public PageViewModelFactory(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        this.services = services;
    }

    public TPageViewModel Create() => services.GetRequiredService<TPageViewModel>(); // Transient
}

var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
    .Where(t => !t.IsInterface).ToList();
// auto-register all type which implements IPage
types.Where(t => typeof(IPage).IsAssignableFrom(t))
    .ToList().ForEach(t => CreateAndAddClosedType(services, typeof(PageViewModelFactory<>), t));

private static void CreateAndAddClosedType(IServiceCollection services, Type openType, Type? type)
{
    var typeArgs = new Type[] { type! };
    var closedType = openType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
    services.AddSingleton(closedType);
}
```

Storing `IServiceProvider` in the Factory class seems to be the service locator ani-pattern but MS DI does the same when we register a Func manually.
Now we can use `PageViewModelFactory<FileHandlingViewModel>.Create` instead of `Func<FileHandlingViewModel>`.